# Use different interfaces (eth0 and wlan0) for sending and receiving in Python program

Tags: python, router

Is it possible to switch between interfaces in Python program?

I will have `eth0` and `wlan0` connection, both are different routers.
I'm using `boto` to upload images to `AWS` server. And I need to upload using router with fast upload speed and for other downloads I need to use another interface which is connected to a router with fast download speed.

If this is possible how I can do it?

Comment: not duplicate because I'm not opening a socket, I'm downloading something and upload it to AWS server using boto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible by using route add command in linux